# jacoco not excluding files and print not working in jacocoTestReport task to debug it

Tags: gradle, jacoco

My full build file is https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/build.gradle

but I am just modifying the jacocoTestReport section to the following.

ie.

1. Clone project
2. replace jacocoTestReport section with my code below
3. Run ./gradlew :webserver:http-router:build
4. open up webserver/http-router/output/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html
5. NOTICE that the Exception classes are still there in the report

The code

```
   jacocoTestReport {
      additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
      sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
      classDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.output.filter { file ->
         if(file.getName().endsWith("Exception.class")) {
            print("Excluded:"+file.getName());
            return false;
         }
         print("Included:"+file.getName());
         return true;
      })
      executionData.from = fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec")
      reports {
          html.enabled = true
          xml.enabled = true
          csv.enabled = false
      }
   }
```

The print statements for debugging are not happening and all the Exception constructors are showing up.  It doesn't even print included files which I don't get at all.